# ELF programmatically resolving function names

Tags: parsing, assembly, elf, disassembly, relocation

Given that the below disassembly is of the start function, and that the address referenced by call at `0x4009d4` is some location in the `.plt`, how can we programmatically determine the name the function that the call references?

Is there a type of step-by-step procedure to do this?

```
----------_start----------
0x4009b0    xor ebp, ebp
0x4009b2    mov      r9,rdx
0x4009b5    pop      rsi
0x4009b6    mov      rdx,rsp
0x4009b9    and      rsp,0xfffffffffffffff0
0x4009bd    push     rax
0x4009be    push     rsp
0x4009bf    mov      r8,0x402850
0x4009c6    mov      rcx,0x4027e0
0x4009cd    mov      rdi,0x402477
0x4009d4    call     0x4008f0
```

Comment: If you have the symbols then use those. Otherwise, disassemble which GOT entry the PLT uses and look up the relocation for it.

Comment: Are you interested in the *name* of the function being called, or its *address* after the loader resolves it?

Comment: I am interested in the name of the function being called